Planner API is throttling too much in Micorosoft Graph
We are developing a sync feature with Planner where user can click the sync button and it will sync the tasks from Planner. The problem is when user initiate the sync multiple time in a short time, the Planner API gets throttled and the subsequence response is delayed by a significant time.
In my research, I have found out that it is something Microsoft does on there end and the solution is to wait. But that will not fulfill our requirement and wondering is there any way exist where we can get the data without throttling?
Here are the code of how we are getting the tasks,
        { PlannerTaskCollectionResponse? result = await _graphServiceClient.Planner.Plans[planId].Tasks.GetAsync();
If there are some paid version of graph API where we get the data without throttling then we will consider it too.

Why don't you prevent the user initiate a sync multiple times? Disable the button for 10 or 20 seconds after it is clicked.

The business does not want to wait to sync. So adding a wait time does not meet the business goal.

You've read this guidance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling
